# Error "Validation failed: Url This field is required!" when create attachment by paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, attachment

My params[attachments]:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff89bac0990 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170119-25970-6hvs90.jpg>, @original_filename="ca.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"job_application[attachments]\"; filename=\"ca.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
```

And when i create by: 
`Attachment.create!( document: params[attachments])`

It show me error: `Validation failed: Url This field is required!`
Any ideal? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Attachment` model you are likely performing some validation like `validates_presence_of :url`

Comment: Ya. I have it. But if i remove it, how can i show url of attachment?

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you so much. Sorry i'm beginer